# ARM процессор на KVM

Tags: администрирование, arm, виртуальная-машина, kvm

Можно ли запустить прошивку с устройства с ARM процессором на KVM?
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если хост-система запущена на [ARM процессоре](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support) с поддержкой виртуализации.

Если хост-система запущена на другой аппаратной архитектуре, то вам необходим не модуль ядра KVM, а [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU). KVM использует аппаратные возможности CPU для виртуализации и может виртуализировать только ту же аппаратную платформу. QEMU же может эмулировать другую аппаратную архитектуру, но, разумеется, эмуляция потребует больше ресурсов хост-системы.

Comment: Хост система - x86. Гостевая ARM. Можно такое реализовать?

Comment: как же медленно оно ворочается. как будто 300МГц\16 ОЗУ =)